# Zend Framework: Create Route For Homepage

Tags: zend-framework

I'm writing an Application at the minute using Zend Framework and it uses database driven routes.

I've disabled default routing, however this seems to be causing an error when accessing the homepage.

Can anyone tell me how to 'recreate' the default route, that would take a user who visited the homepage '/' to the index action of the index controller?

EDIT
@RockyFord, based on your answer, I've added the below:

```
if($this->_frontController->getRequest()->getRequestUri() == '/') {
    $route= new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '*',
        array('controller'  => 'index',
              'action'      => 'index')
    );
    $router->addRoute('default', $route);
)
```

But as you can see, I've had to test to see if we're on the homepage using the URL. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

I can't use this sort of rule, because the forward slash in the route declaration gets stripped out:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('/', array(
    'module' => 'default',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));
$router->addRoute('homepage', $route);
```

Taken from Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static:

```
public function __construct($route, $defaults = array())
{
    $this->_route = trim($route, self::URI_DELIMITER);
    $this->_defaults = (array) $defaults;
}
```

Comment: If you've disabled the default route why would you want to recreate it? You might want to instead add a static route for the homepage only.

Comment: Thanks Tim - but that's what I'm trying to achieve, add a static route to the homepage

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> Route definition can contain one more special character - a wildcard -
>   represented by '*' symbol. It is used to gather parameters similarly
>   to the default Module route (var => value pairs defined in the URI).
>   The following route more-or-less mimics the Module route behavior:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':module/:controller/:action/*',
    array('module' => 'default')
);
$router->addRoute('default', $route);
```

`Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module` has the actual definition of the routes if your interested in the code.

[EDIT]
maybe:

```
//not sure if the name will work or not, might need empty string?
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
    '/',
    array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
);
//also might need a better name like 'home'
$router->addRoute('/', $route);
```

Comment: Thanks for your very quick reply, but this didn't work. I still get the error `exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'No route matched the request' in M:\Zend_Framework\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Rewrite.php:408`

Comment: Sorry I can tell you the route, but I have no idea how your app is set up to use it. Remember though that routes are matched in reverse order so the more generic routes need to registered first. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

A homepage route would just be:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('/', array(
    'module' => 'default',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));
$router->addRoute('homepage', $route);
```

replace the default/index/index values with whichever controller and action you want the request to go to.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but look at the construct for Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static, and you'll see it strips out the forward slashes: `public function __construct($route, $defaults = array())
    {
        $this->_route = trim($route, self::URI_DELIMITER);
        $this->_defaults = (array) $defaults;
    }`

Comment: I know the slashes get stripped off, but they do when the route is matched as well, so it should work. Does that route still give you the "No route matched" error?